Do any hobbits ever use "Sie" in German translations of The Hobbit or The Lord of the Rings?
I read the beginning of Der Herr Der Ringe years ago, but my German wasn't good enough to make it enjoyable.  Moreover, I discovered that the copy I was using (which one of my friends had had specially ordered and imported, in the days before online shopping) was defective; one of the quires was duplicated, leaving another one missing.  So I don't recall how the hobbits addressed one-another, in particular whether they used the polite second person pronoun Sie (the subject of this question as well).
I think it would have sounded very odd if Sam had addressed his beloved Master Frodo with du.  On the other hand, it is an actual plot point (coming up when Pippin meets with Denethor) that the Shire dialect of Westron has lost the polite form of address.  So how have German* translators handled the speech of Hobbits in this regard?
*Although I am personally most interested in German, it would also be interesting to hear about translations into other languages that have a T-V distinction.

I'd love to read about how translations to other languages handle the choice of honorific forms.

Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67962/is-gandalf-really-on-du-terms-with-the-balrog-odd-duzen-example

With regards to LoTR, it would not surprise me if there were a significant difference between the original Carroux translation and the new Krege one. When the Krege translation came out, it was heavily criticized for its use of informal and contemporary language. However, it's been 25 years since I last read the Krege translation and even more for Carroux – I have since preferred the English original.

Btw., the Czech translation, otherwise excellent, uses honorific forms even where that sounds strange for most native speakers, contradicting the scene with Pippin and Denethor.

I don't know about LoTR but the first time I learned about Ihr as an (archaic) formal form for 2nd-person singular was from a translation of The Hobbit where Bilbo uses it to address Gandalf.

Hungarian has the distinction too. The translation uses the informal form as that was the only one used in the middle ages and was preserved in tales from that time (as equivalent to "Du bist müde, Herr Frodo"). The formal version likely came from German at later times.

In French, Sam uses vous with Frodo (and others) and Frodo uses tu when speaking to him. Merry and Pippin use tu between each other. The rest of the fellowship usually use vous between each other (Gimli to Legolas, Aragorn to the hobbits, etc. Even Gandalf to Pippin when he scolds him)

Really not a lot to say except "yes", the Krege translation of The Hobbit uses "Sie" as the formal address (I checked with the Kindle edition, which has been further edited by Joachim Kalka).
The Krege translations of LotR uses formal/informal like any modern German - "du" for friends, family and drinking buddies, "Sie" to express a formal or distanced relationship (e.g. the Sackheim-Beutlins speaking to Merry). Sam actually mixes modes in the beginning, using an informal "du" in Kombination with a more formal "Herr Frodo".

Actually "Herr Frodo" is also a weird combination of formal and informal. Usually addressing people by first/given name goes with "du", while formal addressing is "Sie" and "last/family name" and if available title. So in that case it would either be "du" and "Frodo" or "Sie" and "Herr Beutlin(Baggins)". But "du" + "Herr Frodo" is idk trying to grasp the concept but not quite getting it :)

But "Mr. Frodo" is also a very odd-sounding combination to my American ears, being a mixture of the familiar and formal.  But, then, JRRT lived two generations before me in a society that was always somewhat more formal than that which I grew up in. Fascinating discussion!

@haxor789 absolutely, this does rather sound like an English butler addressing his ward ("Hello Master Bruce").  To be period accurate, so to speak, Sam would either use "Ihr", or "Herr" without the name as a layer of indirection ("Geht es dem Herrn gut?"). So I am not sure what to make of this.

Perhaps Sam (and his father, the Gaffer) got into the habit of saying "Mr Frodo" when both Bilbo & Frodo were at Bag End.

@PM2Ring perhaps, but still - Krege could have used any combination including "Sie" and first name ("Hamburger Sie"), but for some reason chose pretty much the only one that is not in any way idiomatic German, which sabotages to some extent the conceit that this is a translation into modern day language.

@MarkOlson Remember The Godfather? At the end of the movie Don Michael graduates to Don Corleone. "Mr Frodo" is consistent with the King's English of Tolkien's day. As recently I recall the son and heir to a family business (where my mother worked) being addressed as "Mr. [first name]". When he took over the business, the older employees would still use "Mr. [first name]"; only the new ones would say "Mr [surname]". This usage has died out here in New Zealand. I'm not sure when, as I was out of the country for over 20 years.

@EikePierstorff There is also the Münchner Du. It might more less common, but is not unheard of.

As an English English speaker nearing my 7th decade "Mr Frodo" as a mode of address very much evokes the image of unlearned country folk addressing a local person of higher class and learning back sometime in the first half of last century. In other words precisely the relationship between Frodo and Sam.

@EikePierstorff could you give some examples where "Sie" is used. I'd like to check with the Carroux translation but I only have the books, so searching isn't that easy ;-)
